# Cordova App freezes at Splash Screen

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, backbone.js

Here is my problem, the app is built using Backbone.js and Cordova. The app works fine when the network (Internet) is available. But when the Device is offline the app behaves differently during each launch.

When the app freezes it doesn't even reach the App Init code which is the starting point of my app.

-What may be the cause of such unpredictable behavior?

-Would that be a race between the loading of Cordova Plugin (I'm saying this because the console.log() inside one of the plugins do seem to work every time even if the app freezes at splash screen)?

Please have a look at the Cordova plugins used

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inapppurchase" spec="~1.0.0" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="~1.8.0">
        <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="572****26*6" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="com.virtualartifacts.webintent" spec="https://github.com/florentvaldelievre/virtualartifacts-webIntent.git" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="~1.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~4.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="~1.5.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~1.4.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~1.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~3.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" spec="~2.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.2" />
    <plugin name="parse-push-plugin" spec="https://github.com/taivo/parse-push-plugin" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.1.3" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Where should I begin debugging?

Comment: Are you loading some remote javascript or css?

Comment: Nope everything is local

Comment: Does the push-plugin work offline? Put some console.log code in your app and see what is going wrong and use an inspector.

Comment: Tried removing the push plugin.. Still doesn't work..

Comment: why did you tag backone . when you didn't use

Comment: @Mahi - The app itself if build with Backbone.js

Comment: in your able plugin file **com.virtualartifacts.webintent** and **parse-push-plugin"** use internet for load their content try to remove both then try

Comment: @Naitik - Removed both, still doesn't work. I think the spec field in the config.xml has got nothing to do with the final build. It's used to resolve during the build process. But i'm not sure

Comment: can you please debugg and check in console of chrome while runing in device and paste error logs here so we can help you. Thank you

Answer (score -2):

Here are some stuff you should consider.

1. Please make sure that you are calling all javascript and css in local in index.html.
2. In your main javascript, please be sure that all plugin functions are running after deviceready state.
3. Please double check your 'Content-Security-Policy'.
4. For your testing purpose, be sure to change 'AutoHideSplashScreen' setting to true.
5. Please uninstall unused plugins.